# How to replace the 1's in "document.search1.search_text1.value;" with the function parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have skimmed down my code to make it easier to read but this is basically what I have and it is working fine.

```
function findmatch() {

var value = document.search1.search_text1.value;

}
```

But what I want to do is have a parameter x and replace the 1's with the x but I can't seem to do it. I thought the following would work but had no luck with it.

```
function findmatch(x) {

var value = document.'search'+x.'search_text'+x.value;

}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use square bracket notation:

```
function findmatch (x) {
    var value = document['search' + x]['search_text' + x].value;
}
```

To explain a little further, in JS

```
document.search1
```

is the same thing as

```
document['search1']
```

thus, with the latter you can dynamically build names

```
x = 1;
document['search' + x]
```

Comment: Thanks a million JAAulde! Worked perfectly! Just one question. Why do we get rid of the 2 full stops?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What's a "full stop?"

Comment: The dots I mean. Why do we take them out instead of having it like: document.['search' + x].['search_text' + x].value;

Comment: Ah, I dunno, that's just the syntax. In JS, for accessing a hierarchy of properties, you can use dot notation _or_ square bracket notation. No need to use both to get to the same value.